# Getting warning

Tags: c, embedded

I am writing code in embedded c(in Kiel4) comparing String in buffer AtRes with C003 and it will assigned to uc EVENTbuf like

```
else if(ucEVENTBuf=tmMisc_strnstr((INT8C *)AtRes,"C003,",4))
```

now  I am getting warning

```
assignment in condition
```

how to overcome thise warnning.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Your compiler is interprething the if statemente as follows:

```
if( ucEVENTBuf=1 ) // or whatever
```

which is an assignement. As other people said it is usually sufficient to put other parentesis around:

```
if( (ucEVENTBuf=1) ) // or whatever
```

but if also this doesn't work for you, you may try this:

```
else if((ucEVENTBuf=tmMisc_strnstr((INT8C *)AtRes,"C003,",4))!=0) /* <<<<< ask explicitely to compare against 0 */
```

Comment: The last suggestion is advisable in any case since it is a boolean expression while the result of `tmMisc_strnstr()` is not.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace

```
else if(ucEVENTBuf=tmMisc_strnstr((INT8C *)AtRes,"C003,",4))
```

with

```
else if((ucEVENTBuf=tmMisc_strnstr((INT8C *)AtRes,"C003,",4)))
```

Or with

```
else if((ucEVENTBuf=tmMisc_strnstr((INT8C *)AtRes,"C003,",4)) != NULL)
```

If your compiler still gives you the same warning (it should not), then try this

```
else {
    ucEVENTBuf=tmMisc_strnstr((INT8C *)AtRes,"C003,",4);
    if (ucEVENTBuf != NULL) {
    }
}
```

You **may need** do other changes to the structure of your code.

Comment: Thank you for replay but I have tried two ways it's giving same warning

Comment: @KJAGAn You already tried to put the assignment before that `if` statement?

Comment: @Clifford I do not understand your first statement. Anyway, your suggestion is right, using an explicit boolean expression as the condition is better.

Comment: @leeduhem:  Sorry, the comment was aimed at K JAGAn's initial comment - it should have been addressed to him.  Deleting and re-applying.

Comment: @KJAGAn : I doubt the last suggestion is giving the *same* warning since in that case there is no assignment in the conditional. Try again! However I would suggest using an explicit boolean expression in the condition: `if( ucEVENTBuf != 0 )`.

Answer (score 2):

A common error when programming C in the old days was to accidentally use assignment instead of comparison:

```
if (x = 3)
```

So compilers started warning about this.  But if you really mean to assign and use the result as a boolean expression, you can.  Some compilers will not warn if you add parentheses:

```
if ((x = 3))
```

If that isn't enough on your system, you can try to make it more explicit:

```
if (!!(x = 3))
```

Comment: Thank you for replay but I have tried two ways it's giving same warning

Comment: In that case, try doing the assignment as a completely separate statement: `ucEVENTBuf=tmMisc_strnstr(...); if (ucEVENTBuf) ...`.